# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined angular-cli after update

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting the above error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` after I converted and updated my old angular project.

Everything seems to be setup correctly but I am not sure why I am getting this error. I look around SOF and nothing popped out and most were out dated.

I also posted it on GitHub [Link Here](https://github.com/drewjocham/TestDemo.git)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "DemoTestApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
      "test": "karma start",
      "e2e": "protractor"
  },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
        "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
        "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
        "karma": "1.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
        "protractor": "~4.0.13",
        "ts-node": "1.2.1",
        "tslint": "^4.0.2",
        "typescript": "~2.0.3",
        "jest-cli": "*"
    }
}
```

angular-cli:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "name": "Test-Demo"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

If I need to post anything else let me know. This error really has me stumped.

Comment: Please post your angular-cli.json

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski please see updated code. My project is also on GIT, link is in the post. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you trried running `ng init` after updating angular-cli?

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski well it got to to work but broke my project. I have to hook everything back up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear it fixed the error. Use git to diff the changes `ng init` has done to revert your code to working state.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski Up and running just have to fix the old Angular to the new. Fun